# How to view expiration date of code signing cert?

Tags: macos, terminal, certificate, code-signing

I know `pkgutil --check-signature` and `codesign -d -vvv` but neither of them show the expiration date. Is there a way to view the expiration date of a code signing cert? Say for instance...macOS installer.

Comment: Hi Kelbizzle, welcome to Ask Different. You can simply place the certificate on the Desktop, select it, press Space and let Quick Look display all properties, among them its expiration date under "Not valid after". If you are command-line inclined, you can use `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <your certificate> -inform der` (if the certificate is in DER format) or `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <your certificate> -inform pem` (if the certificate is in PEM format) in Terminal. `openssl` is included in macOS under `/usr/bin/openssl`.